# Flash mute button in Actionscript 3.0 doesn't unmute

Tags: flash, actionscript

I'm very much new to Actionscript but I followed a tutorial on creating a mute button which works fine to mute my audio but not to unmute it again after. What's wrong with my code?

```
function setMute(vol){
    sTransform.volume = vol; 
    SoundMixer.soundTransform = sTransform;
}

var sTransform:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform(1,0);
var Mute:Boolean = false;
themutebutton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,toggleMuteBtn);

function toggleMuteBtn(event:Event) {
    if(Mute === false) {
        Mute = true;
        setMute(0);
    } else {
        Mute = false;
        setMute(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers, the problem was actually the var muted being initialised to false. I took off the = false and it fixed my problem.

The class was a little complex for me as a beginner and the answer from igor milla works but only if I take the = false away

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `Sound` class instead:

```
public class YourClass extends Sprite  
{

//  declare the member variables
private var yourSound:Sound = new Sound();
private var muted:Boolean = false;

    private function initializationMethod() 
    {
        yourSound.load(new URLRequest("yourSound.mp3"));
        yourSound.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, yourSoundErrorHandler);

        yourSound.play();

        muteButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, muteButtonClickHandler);         
        this.addChild(muteButton);
    }

    private function muteButtonClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void 
    {
        if ( muted ) 
        {
            muted = false;
            yourSound.play();
            // you might want to change the button text or image here
        }
        else
        {
            muted = true;
            SoundMixer.stopAll();
            // you might want to change the button text or image here
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try rewrite your function this way:

```
function setMute(vol){   
   SoundMixer.soundTransform = new SoundTransform(vol);
}
```

I found it working like this in one of my happily working in the production projects.